# How to decode Unicode characters in string

Tags: java, utf-8

I got a bridge with JavaScript and it gives me some bad input that looks as below, I need to fix it on my side.

```
String input = "\u003chtml\u003e\u003cbody\u003eMoved\u003c/body\u003e\u003c/html\u003e\n";
```

I want to decode it to this output:

```
String output = decode(input);
System.out.println(output);
```

It should print the below line(like in this [nice tool](https://mothereff.in/utf-8#%3Chtml%3E%3Cbody%3EMoved%3C%2Fbody%3E%3C%2Fhtml%3E%0A))

`<html><body>Moved</body></html>`

Comment: The string already has the content you expect (assuming the `String input = "..."` is part of a `.java` file). If it is not, where/how are you getting the data?

Comment: What does it print?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I got a bridge with javascript and some thing goes wrong there, so I need to fix it on my side. This is the input that I am getting

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman You should edit your question with that information, because it is pretty important, and as it stands the code shown doesn't demonstrate your problem.

Comment: `String str = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(path);`

Comment: download jar from here (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi)

Comment: The above is simply `"<html><body>Moved</body></html>"`. Executed as java one gets this value. It is u-escaping, normally of non-ASCII, here of `<` and `>` - maybe for XML. `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava` will help too.